# How to have Pycharm use .csv files from a Google Drive

Tags: python, pycharm, google-drive-api

I am using an application called Screamingfrog to scan my companies sites for broken images/links. Currently, the scans are ran on a remote PC desktop and are on a scheduler that scans each site daily and stores the scan results as .csv files to a Google Drive. We use a remote desktop because the scans significantly slow down my laptop, so I'm unable to use the scan locally on my laptop. What I want to do is some how change the path to use that specific Google Drive and pull the .csv files from there. Then I run a command in Pycharm that takes those files and puts them in a Google Sheet.

So to summarize I basically want to change the path to use a Google Drive instead of locally from my work laptop.

Thank you in advance to anyone trying to help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should look at the Google Drive API Documentation, it facilities pushing and pulling files from your storage.

Here is the link: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python

I couldn't comment on your post because of the new user restrictions